# What is the most efficient way to create a table B identical to table A but with different column ordering?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PG table A with columns (x,y,z), now I needed and added a BIGSERIAL `id` to it but then A ends being like A(x,y,z,id) and I would rather have the columns in the following order: A(id,x,y,z).

I know the only way to accomplish this, is by copying A into a new temporary table B with the desired order, then drop A and rename B to A. I would use `CREATE TABLE B AS SELECT ... FROM A ...` but do I get all the same indexes and constraints as in A? what's the most streamlined simplest way to do this?

Comment: In the dots you could have the desired fields, in the desired order. And having coumns ordered as x,y,z,id or id,x,y,z have no effect on the data stored.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _but do I get all the same indexes and constraints as in A?_ There's one way to find out.

Comment: Why does it matter what order the columns are in by default?

Comment: I use an ORM framework in my stack and I like to keep it tidy and in sync with my actual database deployment. Oh actually I could use my ORM to generate the DDL for that table alone and then INSERT FROM SELECT, good choice.

Comment: I am still curious how to cover this use case in PG alone and without ORM help.